# Como validar un json si vienen parametros nulos en java

Tags: java, json

queria consultarles como puedo validar mediante el if que me ejecute ciertas acciones, lo que pasa es que en un json vienen valores nulos cuando quiero setear los registros que estan en la BD, setear por asi decir los registros que el usuario inserto (editar) este es mi codigo java:

```
if (notificacion.getJson_notif_config() != null) {
            accVenEmer = true;
            booMiniMap = true;
            booleanAcciones();

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(notificacion.getJson_notif_config(), JsonObject.class);
            System.out.println("Que trae: " + jsonObject);
            if (jsonObject.get("url") != null) {
                stringSonido = jsonObject.get("url").getAsString();
                System.out.println("Sonido " +jsonObject);
                if (jsonObject.get("color") != null) {
                    switch (jsonObject.get("color").getAsString()) {
                        case "FF0000":
                            selectedColor1();
                            color1 = true;
                            break;

                        case "FF8000":
                            selectedColor2();
                            color2 = true;
                            break;
                        case "00994C":
                            selectedColor3();
                            color3 = true;
                            break;

                        case "009999":
                            selectedColor4();
                            color4 = true;
                            break;
                        case "0080FF":
                            selectedColor5();
                            color5 = true;
                            break;
                        case "6666FF":
                            selectedColor6();
                            color6 = true;
                            break;
                        case "FF3399":
                            selectedColor7();
                            color7 = true;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

Funciona solo si en el json no vienen ningún null, pero cuando edito otro que si viene null, me genera este error:

```
Que trae: {"url":null,"color":"00994C","minimapa":true}
07-Sep-2018 18:08:09.251 ADVERTENCIA [http-nio-8080-exec-648] com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute /Notificaciones/notificaciones.xhtml @380,262 actionListener="${notificationsBean.selectEditNotificacion(notificacion)}": java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonNull
 javax.el.ELException: /Notificaciones/notificaciones.xhtml @380,262 actionListener="${notificationsBean.selectEditNotificacion(notificacion)}": java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonNull
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at Seguridad.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:625)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1372)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonNull
    at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsString(JsonElement.java:191)
    at avo.ob.notifications.NotificationsBean.selectEditNotificacion(NotificationsBean.java:782)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    ... 36 more
```

Y el que viene lleno seria algo asi:

```
Que trae: {"url":"sonid intervalo","color":"00994C","minimapa":true}
```

Como bien mencioné en la parte de arriba ese json viene un Null, la pregunta es: ¿Hay alguna manera en que pueda forzar esa ejecución? lo que pasa es que viene de un campo que no es obligatorio que el usuario lo inserte, y es por eso que lo plasma null, espero y me pueda dar a entender, quedo al pendiente, buena tarde.

Comment: Esto puede ser un tema propio de la **librería Gson** deberías consultar la doc de la misma. De todos modos creo que sería mejor que tu json no lleve valores nulos, quizá puedas analizar si los tiene para cada un de los campos y asignar un valor por defecto en ese caso, como un string vacío. Mira este hilo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324760/gson-jsonobject-unsupported-operation-exception-null-getasstring

Answer (score 1):

El error se provoca precisamente porque el valor que tratas de obtener no existe en el json.

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonNull
>       at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsString(JsonElement.java:191)

Para validar valores null se realiza mediante el método **[isNull()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html#isNull)**

```
 //if (jsonObject.get("url") != null) {
  if(!jsonObject.isNull("url")) {
```

> **[isNull()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html#isNull)** : Devuelve verdadero si el valor en la ubicación especificada
>   en esta array es JsonValue.NULL.

Comment: Hola ya usé ese metodo pero desafortunadamente no me funcione ya que en parte si funciona pero en otro modulo si le afecta :(

Comment: @cratus666jose en que parte te afecta, agrega más detalles.

Comment: Es ahi mismo, en el codigo de arriba ya que si pongo el metodo isNull en donde dice de los colores aqui "if (jsonObject.get("color") != null)" ya no se me setean los valores en otro modulo de la aplicación.

Comment: Estoy metiendo esto: jsonObject.isJsonNull() dentro de uno de los IF, y si funciona, pero en otro validador ya no funciona, es decir si edito otro registro ya no setea los valores :(

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar estas dos funciones:

Con esta funcion verificas si existe el atributo "url"

```
objJson.has("url")
```

Y con esta funcion verificas si es null

```
objJson.isNull("url")
```

Answer (score 0):

ya pude solucionar en cierta parte este problema, lo que fue hacer otro if, uno para los null, y otro para los que no, asi fue como quedo:

```
if (jsonObject.isJsonNull()) {
                stringSonido = jsonObject.get("url").getAsString();
                System.out.println("Sonido " + jsonObject);
            }

            if (jsonObject.get("color") != null) {
                switch (jsonObject.get("color").getAsString()) {
                    case "FF0000":
                        selectedColor1();
                        color1 = true;
                        break;

                    case "FF8000":
                        selectedColor2();
                        color2 = true;
                        break;
                    case "00994C":
                        selectedColor3();
                        color3 = true;
                        break;

                    case "009999":
                        selectedColor4();
                        color4 = true;
                        break;
                    case "0080FF":
                        selectedColor5();
                        color5 = true;
                        break;
                    case "6666FF":
                        selectedColor6();
                        color6 = true;
                        break;
                    case "FF3399":
                        selectedColor7();
                        color7 = true;
                }

            }
```

Si existe alguna otra forma, se los agradecería si me la dijeran por favor, pero en si ya no me causa conflictos, saludos y buena vibra.